# Laravel AJAX Post array becomes empty on server

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, laravel, post

I have two arrays in my AJAX Post. One works always, the other one becomes empty on server. Before they are sent they look identical to me, thats why I am super puzzled why it does not work.

Array A, which works always `console.log()`:

```
0: "content_description_back_button"
1: "search_city_no_results"
```

Array B, which becomes empty `console.log()`:

```
search_city_no_results_x: "No results. Please change your search query"
content_description_back_button_xxx: "back"
```

The POST code:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/home/update_xml',
    type : "post",
    data : {'new_keys': array_B, 'deactivate_keys': array_A},
    success : function(response) {
        console.log("update_xml", response);    
    },
    error : function(xhr) {
        console.log("update_xml", xhr);
    }
});
```

Server `\Log::info($data->new_keys);`:

Just an empty string, nothing.

Server `\Log::info($data->deactivate_keys);`:

```
array (
  0 => 'content_description_back_button',
  1 => 'search_city_no_results',
)
```

What I have done so far:

I have tried tons of different syntax combinations for the AJAX post.

Examples:

```
contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
dataType: "json",
data : JSON.stringify({'new_keys': array_B, 'deactivate_keys': array_A})
```

I tried `contentType` -> `ContentType`

I tried different combinations, but the results are always the same. Array A works always. Array B is empty on server.

In the `console.log()` they look both identical to me. They are both threated as an array.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($data);`?

Comment: Its weird. I am struggling for almost 1 hour, but right after I created this thread I found the solution. Array B should be threated as a dict in JS. I had `array_b=[];` before population it, but it must be `array_b={};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array_B must be threated as a dictionary in JS.

Before populating it, it looked like this:

```
array_b=[];
```

But it must look like this:

```
array_b={};
```

Very simple fix. I keep the question open. Maybe someone will have a similar issue.